# How to get the current token while creating custom token for more than one facet field?

Tags: xconnect, exm

I'm trying to create custom tokens for more than one facet field. 
`GetMyCustomFacetValue` (this MyCustomFacet facet) is my function to return the responding value to the current token for examlpe (`$firstname`, `$lastname`). I need to get the current token to decide  which facet field value to return

```
namespace FooBar
{
    public class CustomRecipientPropertyTokenMap : DefaultRecipientPropertyTokenMap
    {
        protected static readonly MethodInfo GetMyFacetValue = typeof(FacetExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(FacetExtensions.GetMyCustomFacetValue), new[] { typeof(MyCustomFacet) });

        static CustomRecipientPropertyTokenMap()
        {
            if (TokenBindings == null)
            {
                TokenBindings = new Dictionary<Token, RecipientPropertyTokenBinding>();
            }

            RecipientPropertyTokenBinding customTokenBinding = RecipientPropertyTokenBinding.Build<MyCustomFacet>(new Token("customtokenkey"), null, GetMyFacetValue);
            TokenBindings.Add(customTokenBinding.Token, customTokenBinding);
        }
    }

    public static class FacetExtensions
    {
        public static string GetMyCustomFacetValue (this MyCustomFacet facet)
        {
         //I need the current token that calls this function
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a separate extension method for each custom token that you have. The `GetMyCustomFacetValue` method doesn't receive a `currentToken` parameter, that's why it cannot cater for all of the custom tokens that are related to the `MyCustomFacet`.

So, what you should be doing instead is something like:

```
public static class FacetExtensions
    {
        public static string GetFoo (this MyCustomFacet facet)
        {
          return facet.Foo;
        }

        public static string GetBar (this MyCustomFacet facet)
        {
          return facet.Bar;
        }
    }
}
```

Another option is to use pass a `Func<MyCustomFacet, object>` to the `RecipientPropertyTokenBinding.Build` method, this will save you couple of lines of code.

```
RecipientPropertyTokenBinding.Build<MyCustomFacet>(new Token("foo"), myCustomFacet => myCustomFacet.Foo, null),
RecipientPropertyTokenBinding.Build<MyCustomFacet>(new Token("bar"), myCustomFacet => myCustomFacet.Bar, null),
```